# Divs Sliding Outside Window Size on jQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate

I'm changing the position of a group of divs from absolute to relative upon clicking so that they'll slide into their own spots. Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sn9L1gr9/1/

```
$('div.box').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("move");
  $(this).animate({
    'left': '160px'
  });
});
```

It works except for an extra div being added to each row before breaking onto the next row. So looking at the jfiddle on a 1366x768 monitor with the four windows evenly sized, it should be:

Div1 -- Div2
Div3 -- Div4
Div5 -- Div6
Div7

But instead it's organizing as:

Div1 -- Div2 -- Div3
Div4 -- Div5 -- Div6
Div7

and adding a scrollbar.

So I'm wondering how I can get the divs to break properly (including utilizing the column that contains original absolutely positioned divs). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow.. Looks cool! I can't find an "extra" div.

Answer (score 0):

Since I know the width of the divs, I ended up putting them in a container set to 100% width and subtracting the width of one div from the container width:

```
$("#container").css('width','100%').css('width','-=170px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sn9L1gr9/2/